# center image and keep same height

Tags: html, css, image, overflow

how can i center image using css only within parent div without changing original size?

```css
.main-img {
            display: block;
            width: 180px;
            overflow: hidden;
            align-self: flex-start;
        }
```

```html
<div class="main-img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x50.png" width="1280px" height="550px" alt="main image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way1:**
*horizontally:*

```
.main-img img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

*vertically:*

```
.main-img {
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-img img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

**Way2:**
*horizontally:*

```
.main-img {
  /* ... other code here such as width and height ... */
  position: relative;
}
.main-img img {
  position: relative; 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

*vertically:*

```
.main-img {
  /* ... other code here such as width and height ... */
  position: relative;
}
.main-img img {
  position: relative; 
  top: 50%; 
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

*vertically and horizontally:*

```
.main-img {
  /* ... other code here such as width and height ... */
  position: relative;
}
.main-img img {
  position: relative; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To horizontally center your element, you're looking for `margin: 0 auto`, as `<div>` elements are **[block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** by default (and thus you don't actually need `display: block`):

```css
.main-img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x50.png" width="1280px" height="550px" alt="main image" />
</div>
```

**Vertical** centering is a little more complicated, and it's easiest to achieve both horizontal and vertical centering with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), utilising the `display: flex`, `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` property values. Note that you'll also need to specify a `height` property:

```css
.main-img {
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-img img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x140.png" alt="main image" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It was helpful thank you. 
but why did you add padding in the vertical version? and i added width 480px. i think all the problem was with `display: block` and add `justify-content:center`